# Why my Ant delete does not work?

Tags: java, ant

Using Ant 1.8.0

```
<target name="main">
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="target/xxx/WEB-INF/lib" casesensitive="yes">
            <filename name="junit-*.jar"/>
            <filename name="gin-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

When I run this Ant script, nothing happened, if I leave only one  seem it works. I checked out the Ant FileSet Type, http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html, seem two  does not matter.

So anybody who can tell me what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete isn't succeeding because your files don't match *both* of the `filename` selectors you specified.  From [the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html):

> If any of the selectors within the FileSet do not select the file, the
>   file is not considered part of the FileSet. This makes a FileSet
>   equivalent to an <and> selector container.